# What file systems does Apple use in iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios, hfs+, hfs

## HFS

WWDC 2012 Session 709, ￼*What’s New in the File System*, presented by Deric Horn included the following observation: [Journaled HFS+ everywhere](http://pastebin.com/k46v02yv).

In the iOS Developer Library, [NSDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) contains references to *HFS*.

Do iPhones use HFS Plus?

Journaled or not journaled?

I'd like an authoritative reference. Thanks.

---

### Types of HFS Plus

iOS and iPhone aside for a moment … Apple's [hdiutil(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) lists four HFS *filesystem types* for creation purposes:

- HFS+
- HFS+J (JHFS+)
- HFSX
- JHFS+X

---

#### Postscript

Beyond [the accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107887/8546) … as Apple sometimes distinguishes between **JHFS+X** (journaled, case sensitive) and **HFSX**, so:

- extra kudos to anyone who can verify [whether, in an iPhone, **both** HFSX slices are journaled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/108166/8546)

… I do have fileXray, but I don't foresee myself making an ssh connection to my first generation iPhone ;-)

Comment: Background: https://twitter.com/jollyjinx/status/395193114941734912 observes breakage of an original photo on an iPhone.

Comment: Weird, I sought answers a few times before posting this question. I don't know how the duplicate was missed. Maybe because I sought iPhone instead of iOS. I'll add a tag to the earlier question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**According to [iOS Forensic Analysis](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BZV_wpGHTcEC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), the main filesystem is HFSX**.

> #### HSFX
>
> All Apple mobile devices use HFSX as the file system. HFSX is a variation of HFS+ with one major difference. HFSX is case sensitive.

HFSX is reported by Apple as [Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Case-Sensitive)](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH8289).

There are two main partitions of HFSX: the OS and the user data. Prior to these partitions is the usual MBR partition (around 100 MB).

---

SSHing into my jailbroken iOS 6 device seems to support this, since I can create case-sensitive directories. Creating the following directories was no problem:

```
$ mkdir test
$ mkdir Test
$ mkdir TEST
```

Comment: In the book neither *JHFS+X* nor *JHFSX* is mentioned, which made me wonder whether it's case-sensitive *without* a journal. But then, where Sean Morrissey uses [fileXray](http://filexray.com): **kHFSVolumeJournaled (volume has a journal)** … I wonder whether that's true for both HFSX slices of the disk. I'll add something to the question.

Comment: If all goes well, after iOS 10.3 they will be using APFS: https://arstechnica.com/apple/2017/01/ios-10-3-will-be-apples-first-update-to-convert-storage-to-apfs/